# PHP Array Key & value Question

Tags: php, variables

Hi I writed a test code as below.

```
<?php
$url = 'http://localhost/events/result/cn_index.php?login';

print_r(parse_url($url));

echo parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);


?>
```

Output

```
Array ( [scheme] => http [host] => localhost [path] => /events/result/cn_index.php [query] => login ) /events/result/cn_index.php
```

Now I inserted the line below

```
echo array[query]; // I want to echo 'login', but failed.
```

How to get the value of 'login'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$parsed = parse_url($url);
echo $parsed['query'];
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```
$output = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
echo $output['query'];
```

Comment: @hsz,
Tested with your code, but Output `/` on my winxp XAMPP dev environment. Thank you.

Comment: So in `$output['query']` is just `/` ;)